# Time lag between software update and inclusion in the repositories

Tags: software-center

I noticed that there is a time lag of several days between a software update (for example "chromium") and their inclusion in the repositories! Is there certain criteria that software has to meet, before Ubuntu releases it into the repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly that it doesn't dump core on startup or cause other things to break in an unmodified vanilla install.  It's called "release engineering".